# Is there a parameter after mailto: that I can plug in to have a user send an email to themselves?

Tags: html, mailto

I am using the following email link to send an email to a mobile user from their iPhone or Android device:

> mailto:   ?subject=Enterprise%20Mobile%20Device%20Management&body=Emailing%20https://prod.secureforms.blahblahblah.com/content/verify?docID=78968460-A035-4B8D-B167-EA9586DEAC63&cid=WB294&aName=EPMBL&src=web&aType=report&region=us

The email client pops up but the user has to type in their email address to themselves.

Is there a parameter that I can place after mailto: so that the user's email can automatically be sent to their own email address?

Here is an additional update:

When you do this:mailto: ?subject=Mobility%20and%20Security%20-%20Dazzling%20Opportunities,%20Profound%20Challenges&body=Thank%20you%20for%20your%20interest%20in%20McAfee%20mobile%20security%20solutions.%20%20To%20download%20your%20document,%20copy%20and%20paste%20the%20following%20link%20into%20your%20browser%20address%20bar%20or%20if%20the%20link%20is%20activated%20simply%20click%20:%20%20https://prod.secureforms.mcafee.com/content/verify?docID=45AFAF5B-4199-4A1B-8356-053C66478FE7%26cid=WB236%26aName=EPMBL%26src=web%26aType=report%26region=us,

the iOS interprets %26region as a trademark. You need to convert %26 as 0x26 instead. 0x26 is utf-8 for ampersand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically put the recipient address before the `?`, i.e. `mailto:some@guy.com?subject=something&body=important%20message`. There's no parameter that automatically specifies that the message should be sent to the sender's own address. See one of [these](http://www.mailto.co.uk/) [sources](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/learn-mailto-syntax/6748/) for more info on syntax.